# Insert navigation property if it doesn't exist or just use it if it does exist without key

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I have 2 tables:

```
Person table - 
       PersonID
       Name (unique index).
Orders table - 
       OrderID
       Price
       Item
       PersonID (FK)
```

I want to do an insert to the orders table (using EF) that will insert a list of orders (all with the same person and I only know the person name), I want that if the person doesn't exist in the person table he would be inserted into it and he does exist the order would be populated with the right person.
I don't want to first query whether the person is in the person table because its a redundant call.
Is there any possibility to add it only during the save changes and query the server before hand?
something like that:

```
Person thePerson = new Person {Name = "knownName"};
foreach (var order in orders)
{
   context.Orders.AddObject(new Order
   {
      Price = order.Price,
      Item = order.ItemName,
      Person = thePerson
   });
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I can't see how. Can I ask why you consider querying for the user a redundant call?

Comment: because this can happen a lot in my DB (the code I wrote is a simplified version...) - so it can cause me to the the round trip to the DB many times instead of just doing this once.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the Person object with Name attribute, if you use PersonID attribute, EF does what you want. But this behavior is limited to primary keys, so I do not think it is possible to employ Name to achieve this.

```
Person thePerson = new Person {PersonID = Id}; // Id is either previously fetched or a newly created one
foreach (var order in orders)
{
   context.Orders.AddObject(new Order
   {
      Price = order.Price,
      Item = order.ItemName,
      Person = thePerson
   });
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: this is what I wanted to avoid (fetching the ID...).

Comment: It seems strange; how do you know the name of the person; I bet you are fetching it from database; then way not fetching the ID as well?

Comment: @daryal, could you provide some more details on how to do that? I get a `DbEntryValidationException`...